# Excel calculate fraction

Tags: excel

I'm creating a simple table which has one of the columns displaying fractions and the other column displaying its equivalent decimal value. However since I'm not experienced with excel such a small task proves to be quite difficult for me.

For example I have 1/16 in one column and 0.0625 in the other. I can only get it to display what's in the fraction column 1 through =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1)), but it refuses to do the math, when I force it using VALUE it coverts it into a date!

Also, how do I add increments to the first row so that the next row has the related increment multiple added to the initial value?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

No matter how it is displayed, Excel stores numeric values as numbers (and decimals), not as fractions.

But when you enter `1/16` into a cell, Excel will convert that to a date.

Perhaps you can

- enter `.0625` into A1
- Format A1 as a fraction (e.g. `1/16` if you want 16ths)
- B1:  `=A1`  (formatted as `General`)
- A2:  `=A1 + 0.0625`
- B2:  `=A2`

Then select `A2` and fill down; then `B1` and fill down

[image]

If you prefer to have simplified fractions, you can use the same setup as above, but merely change the format in column A to `??/??`.

If you might be using a different formula to generate the values (one that does not generate values as close to 16th's as this one), but you want to see it simplified to the nearest 16th, then you should round the results of that formula to the nearest 16th

```
=MROUND(your_formula,1/16)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was unaware that cells can be formatted so that their numerical value can be displayed as fractions. What you've achieved here comes close to what I'm looking for, but just two small problems: 1. Although the value is displayed as fractions, they're not in their simplest form, 2/16 should be displayed as 1/8.    2. Shouldn't there be a simple formula that recursively adds the increment to the next row's value, e.g. CURRENT ROW = PREVIOUS ROW + INCREMENT, this way I don' have to manually write A2= A1 + 1/16, A3 = A2 + 1/16...

Comment: If you do as I wrote:  *select A2 and fill down*, excel will automatically make those changes for you.  If you want simplified fractions, you need a slightly different formula and formatting.  I will edit my post to show that.

Comment: Ah I see, such a hole in my knowledge, thanks for the tip and taking the time to explain.